# Parsing date.time for date of birth

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, date, datetime

anyone know whats the best way to get date of birth im only able to find date and time and trying to parse it as a string wont update or delete from the database i get this **error**

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error:

> Line 96:                 int labID =
>   int.Parse(hdfID.Value.ToString()); Line 97:  Line 98:
>   _strMessage(objLab.commitUpdate(labID, txt_patientidI.Text, txt_testCodeI.Text, txt_patientcodeI.Text, txt_ageI.Text,
>   txt_refrangeI.Text, txt_result1I.Text, txt_result2I.Text,
>   txt_resultDescI.Text, txt_sexI.Text, txt_testTypeI.Text,
>   txt_unitsI.Text, txt_abnormalI.Text, Line 99:
>   (DateTime.ParseExact(txt_dobI.Text,"yyyy/mm/dd",null))),"update");
>   Line 100:                 _subRebind();

what should i use for date of birth im using sql server c# .net want to parse that to string to show in my textbox thanks

Comment: What is the value of `txt_textbox.Text` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateTime.ParseExact`. instead of `DateTime.Parse`

```
this.Text="22/11/2009";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: I just gave , How to use DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: I tried    DateTime.ParseExact(txt_dobI.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy", null())), "update"); its asking for a method name and nt taking null i cant use the "this" as im using entries from sql server database i want it to parse whats in there. once i can close this properly think it will work? any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is the structure you'll need to use.

Whenever you just want the date, you can use `DateTime.Date` to get just the date component.

Now, if you're parsing something in a format which is different to what one would generally expect, you can define the format the parser will look at by using the ParseExact function instead.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_dobI.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null);
```

The list of the actual formats can be obtained from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

However in short

dd/MM/yyyy - British/EU/Lots of Places Format

MM/dd/yyyy - American Format

yyyy/MM/dd - Standard Format

Answer (score 0):

I was working with wpf application I did this and it worked out for me.

```
                DateTime DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(DOBText.Text.ToString(),
               "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```